# My databaseReference's valueEventListener onDataChange method will not fire

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Activity where I gather all the data from a particular user and display it, this onDataChange method fires correctly displaying the data perfectly.

```
final User user = new User();

     databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
         {
             user.setFirstName(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getFirstName());
             view_profile_firstName.setText(user.getFirstName().toString());

             user.setLastName(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getLastName());
             view_profile_lastName.setText(user.getLastName().toString());

             user.setEmail(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getEmail());
             view_profile_email.setText(user.getEmail().toString());

             user.setAge(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getAge());
             view_profile_age.setText(Integer.toString(user.getAge()));

             user.setGender(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getGender());
             view_profile_gender.setText(user.getGender());

             user.setProfileComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getProfileComplete());
             view_profile_profileComplete.setText(String.valueOf(user.getProfileComplete()));

         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
         {

         }
     });
```

Although now I am trying to check if the profileComplete is true or not on the current user logging in. The way I want this to work is once the user registers for an account his data is stored as empty strings and profileComplete is set to false. Once all data is filled in and he saves his profile, profileComplete with be set to true. Reason for this is when they log back in after closing the app I want it to bring them to there main screen instead of running them back through the profile creation.

This is what my logging in activity looks like after they have successfully logged in with an email and password.

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                final User user = new User();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful login!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Dialog related to alerting the user we are logging them in
                progressDialog.cancel();

                //Check if logging in user has completed profile or not.
                databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users/" + firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        user.setProfileComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getProfileComplete());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                    {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "COULD NOT RECIEVE PROFILECOMPLETE FROM DATABASE");
                    }
                });

                //The profileComplete method returns TRUE, so we can skip the profile creation.
                if(user.getProfileComplete())
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                //the profileComplete method returns FALSE, we must send the user to the profile creation.
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

I have browsed stackoverflow for roughly 45miniutes to an hour viewing all sorts of solutions such as trying to use Asynchronous processing.

My hypothesis is that because this is all being run on the main thread the onDataChange method does not recieve its data intime to be used for the if statement. Although to try and resolve this I put the

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
```

In a while loop with a boolean variable set to false that would only be set to true after the onDataChanged() method fired. Although this never seemed to go off either so now im quite confused.

All help is much appreciated and please send links to documentation that I could read up on to further my understanding associated with this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to this problem is already described by you in the question.So, one way to solve this problem is as below -

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users/" + firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        user.setProfileComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getProfileComplete());

        //The profileComplete method returns TRUE, so we can skip the profile creation.
        if(user.getProfileComplete()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        //the profileComplete method returns FALSE, we must send the user to the profile creation.
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "COULD NOT RECIEVE PROFILECOMPLETE FROM DATABASE");
    }
});
```

Comment: but will a solution like this always make sure I receive the data before attempting to use the conditional statements? If not I need to figure out a way to stall the main thread until I get that response back. Thank you again for the information and I will be sure to give it a try!

Comment: Yes definitely, as onDataChange will execute when you receive the data. Moreover you can check dataSnapshot.exists and != null.

Comment: Before heading off to bed I just had to give it a try and it worked absolutely amazing. Thank you so much I am still very new to android development and threads are still very much confusing to me. If you dont mind could you explain it a little more on how that actually works, as to what makes your solution different from mine? I'm trying to understand what causes my old "solution" to always return a false profile completely.

Comment: Refer https://academy.realm.io/posts/android-threading-background-tasks/